# How to fix a Layout cast error when setting an adapter for an Android ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a strange issue setting up an adapter for a ListView, the ListView is inside the CandidateView of a custom keyboard, I use a class that inherit of `AsyncTask` class to execute an API call that returns me a list of items to be displayed on a ListView, in the method `onPostExecute()` of `AsyncTask` I take the search results and add to an ArrayList, then this array is being passed to the adapter using the method `updateResults()`, and finally set the ListView's adapter, everything is fine until here, the code compiles, but during runtime I get the next error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>      Process: ....., PID: 5326
>      java.lang.ClassCastException: >android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to >android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
>          at >android.widget.ListView.clearRecycledState(ListView.java:545)
>          at android.widget.ListView.resetList(ListView.java:532)
>          at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:475)
>          at >......KeyboardIME$SearchAsyncTask.onPostExecute(KeyboardIME.java:2325)
>          at >......KeyboardIME$SearchAsyncTask.onPostExecute(KeyboardIME.java:2195)
>          at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:667)
>          at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
>          at >android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:684)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>          at >com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.>java:886)
>          at >com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Based on what it said it is a casting error, but I'm not using a `FrameLayout` on any of the XML files related to the view, also the line 2195 is where the inner `AsyncTask` class starts and the line 2325 is where I set the adapter for the ListView, this adapter is a basic class inherited from `BaseAdapter`.

Here are the code lines I execute as described above:

```
List<SearchItem> searchResults = new ArrayList<>(serverResults);
keyboardInstance.get().mAdapter.updateResults(searchResults);
keyboardInstance.get().resultListView.setAdapter(keyboardInstance.get().mAdapter);
```

Comment: I have the same issue, any help? to fix "java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams"

Comment: It's been 12 days but I fix this issue like 5 days ago, the solution that worked for me was to change the `ListView` for a `RecyclerView` this is a more advanced and flexible version of `ListView`.